# Loop is not vectorized when variable extent is used

Tags: c++, vectorization, sse, compiler-optimization, simd

Version A code is not vectorized while version B code is vectorized.

How to make version A vectorize and keep the variable extents (without using literal extents)?

The nested loop is for multiplication with broadcasting as in numpy library of python and matlab. Description of broadcasting in numpy library is [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Version A code (no std::vector. no vectorization.)

This only uses `imull   (%rsi), %edx` in `.L169`, which is not a SIMD instruction.

[gcc godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g62,options:'-msse4.2+-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-O3',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QHsDOAXATggQwFsA%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%2BGkaCNTZvl2M0LWI7BSIw6jfnWY1yIQNwMK6E4XhyejSI3B1YzABUlRVftuMHPiSKQNCo2E0SKy445ByPLsIFCG8oOiODdMI0kEgRIzTzLBBcDU/YJGYBhNLgbS4OEesyn0gykCM6yyyQHQoCgTAkABayIGYJACHwLzmGQAAjXB0AIOBHBwcAAHMQt/BBMEYCyvAUEBGzQ0QQAtH0NNhUdKhKuF10w2FQwqmI3IRMjuJCvyPOwVFR2nb18jcDTGTK9ZQn6/FlO6RlaqGqJoga0bkAIVqbP69JhC6gzitCYQoLHDTNuqCDNo0eodqmhr/GOFqkDajattW1yIQKntUVaPkUVK%2BM%2BoiZ72MmwlBs2r7mOui07pyfL/Q%2B1omKhFFxtuu7BOjHK4XaWSo1CMGvRBpAkwMnHsYjEsGDEh1HgbJqVMmIAA)),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef int32_t DATA_TYPE;
template <size_t N>
size_t cal_size(size_t (&Ashape)[N]){
    size_t size = 1;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) size *= Ashape[i];
    return size;
}
template <size_t N>
size_t * cal_stride(size_t (&Ashape)[N] ) {
    size_t size = cal_size(Ashape);

    size_t * Astride = new size_t[N];
    Astride[0] = size/Ashape[0];
    for(size_t i = 1; i < N; ++i){
        Astride[i] = Astride[i-1]/Ashape[i];
    }
    return Astride;
}
template <size_t N>
DATA_TYPE * init_data( size_t (&Ashape)[N] ){
    size_t size = cal_size(Ashape);
    DATA_TYPE * data = new DATA_TYPE[size];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        data[i] = i + 1;
    }
    return data;
}

template <size_t N>
void print_data(DATA_TYPE * Adata, size_t (&Ashape)[N] ){
    size_t size = cal_size(Ashape);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        std::cout << Adata[i] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(void){
    constexpr size_t nd = 3;
    size_t Ashape[] = {20,3,4};
    size_t Bshape[] = {1,3,1};
    auto Astride = cal_stride(Ashape);
    auto Bstride = cal_stride(Bshape);

    auto Adata = init_data(Ashape);
    auto Bdata = init_data(Bshape);

    size_t c[nd] = {0,0,0};
        ///counter
    size_t hint[nd] = {0,2,0};
        //hint tells which are the broadcasting axes.
    size_t A_i, B_i;
    for(c[0] = 0; c[0] < Ashape[0]; ++c[0]){ // Ashape as hint[0] = 0
        for(c[1] = 0; c[1] < Bshape[1]; ++c[1]){ //Bshape as hint[1] = 2
            for(c[2] = 0; c[2] < Ashape[2];++c[2]){ //Asape as hint[2] = 0
                A_i = c[0]*Astride[0] + c[1]*Astride[1] + c[2]*Astride[2];
                B_i = c[1]*Bstride[1];
                Adata[A_i] *= Bdata[B_i];
            }
        }
    }
    print_data(Adata, Ashape);
}
```

Version B Code (no std::vector. literal extents, and this vectorizes)

This uses `pmulld  %xmm3, %xmm2` in `.L20`, which is a SIMD instruction.

[gcc godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g62,options:'-msse4.2+-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-O3',sourcez:AQ4YgSwOwYwGwK4BMCmwA8ED2BnALgE4oCGAtgHwBQo408ya6%2BS0eAdABZU14CeADilQAzYKwDMAJgD6eYABEAggBVF05QE0ACgFEA3NVCGQx4ADcsEJMH4FW0pMTzEAFEtXrtO4ACpgix2cAGmAcCAAvFFlQiLQASgBvUxphLAIXMMjoiGAAXmAABj0xDBjI4oBqCohE5JpQZgAuRpgsBDl0dH9A4gBtCABdDC6AIhCRg3rQAF86kCaWto6uhZQoJDhJmdNTVmBSYmgXCytaqZAJGTkApz7JABYCga2py%2BiAIR7e8We5sqjrtIICF3kCQsCAFZBADWL3qqXSOXyRRKXUkKKqNSS53haRcELyhWKBK64kqFQhZxx5wRLmhhJR9K69z0VWhVOp1LUSLEPgAjJJgBVgBCfPchcBofy4ZypqCeaK%2BTLZTQbs5etyhj58p9br15b8VTRZiqTeczVNbPYei41cQQg8CnE4dMgAAA%3D)),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef int32_t DATA_TYPE;


void print_data(DATA_TYPE * Adata, size_t size ){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        std::cout << Adata[i] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(void){
    int32_t Adata[240];
    int32_t Bdata[3];
    size_t A_i, B_i, i,j,k;
    for(i = 0; i < 20; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            for(k = 0; k < 4;++k){
                A_i = i*12 + j*4 + k*1;
                B_i = j*1;
                Adata[A_i] *= Bdata[B_i];
            }
        }
    }
    print_data(Adata, 240);
}
```

boost multiarray vectorize but why?
Not sure if it use simd alignment for memory.

[gcc godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g62,options:'-msse4.2+-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-O3',sourcez: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)),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int 
main () {
  // Create a 3D array that is 3 x 4 x 2
  int d1,d2,d3;
  typedef boost::multi_array<int, 3> array_type;
  typedef array_type::index index;
  array_type A(boost::extents[d1][d2][d3]);
  array_type B(boost::extents[1][d2][1]);
  // Assign values to the elements

  for(index i = 0; i != d1; ++i) 
    for(index j = 0; j != d2; ++j)
      for(index k = 0; k != d3; ++k)
        A[i][j][k] *= B[0][j][0];

  for(index i = 0; i != d1; ++i) 
    for(index j = 0; j != d2; ++j)
      for(index k = 0; k != d3; ++k)
        std::cout << A[i][j][k];
  return 0;
}
```

[2004 pdf](ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/summit/2004/High%20Level%20Loop%20Optimizations.pdf) at gcc.gnu.org that describes some loop optimization of gcc. I hope the "Symbolic Chrecs" (which corresponds to unanalyzed variables) means gcc can fuse nested loop with variable extents.

The last resort is to implement loop fusion with meta-programming.

Comment: he compiler can vectorize loop with variable extents, as described in Richard Hodges' answer to my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724268/can-compiler-optimize-loop-with-variable-length

Comment: may be i should try Fortran next time. Or specify the dimension of the arrays in the make file and recompile the program whenever I change the dimension of the arrays... this means all loops will use literal extents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to test dependencies between memory accesses within and across loop iterations, the array indices (in the polyhedral model of compilation), should have the form `i*c0 + j*c1 + k*c2 + ...`, where `i, j, k ...` are loop counters and `c0, c1, c2 ...` are integer constants.

In your example, apparently the problem is with `c[2] * Astride[2]`, because `Astride[2]` is not a constant.

Indeed, leaving the expression

```
A_i = c[0]*Astride[0] + c[1]*Astride[1] + c[2];
```

allows the loop to be vectorised.

https://godbolt.org/g/gOUVfE

(edit: Note that `X = Adata + c[0]*Astride[0] + c[1]*Astride[1]` is a loop invariant, so within the innermost loop we have just array `X` and index `c[0]`).

Now, the question is how to trickle down a constant in the place of `AStride[2]`. Fortunately, it seems from your calculation in `cal_stride`, the last one is always 1. So we should be done.

Comment: is it true that only the inner-most loop is vectorized?